# Count number of Yes/No entries in a column promoted from InfoPath

Tags: 2010, infopath, chart-web-part, form-library

Using SP 2010, I'm trying to find a way that I can count the number of Yes/No entries in a column of a Form Library. The goal is to display the counts in a Chart Web Part.

The column contains values that have been promoted from a boolean field in the InfoPath form.

I should note that I am aware of the method of using a secondary list and two lookup columns to count the related entries. The problem with this method is that I want the values in the Yes/No column to be promoted from the InfoPath form, and a boolean cannot be promoted into a lookup column (as far as I know).